# Need Help Passing My A Variable From My Method

Tags: java

I'm new to the Java environment and need some help passing a variable from the `gatheringInfo` to `printVariable` method.  The `myVar` variable is not being passed on the `printVariable` method.

```
public class variableTest {
 private float myVar;

 public void setMyVar(float num) {
  myVar = num;
 }
 public variableTest() {
  this.myVar = 0;
 }

 public variableTest(float myVar) {
  this.myVar = myVar;
 }

 public void gatheringInfo() {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter Value: ");
  while (!scnr.hasNextFloat()) {
   System.out.println("Needs To Be An Float Type!");
   scnr.next();
  }
  float myVar;
  this.myVar = scnr.nextFloat();
 }

 public void printVariable() {
  System.out.println("Value: " + myVar);
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Would You like to add a value?");
  String response = scnr.next();
  if (response.toLowerCase().equals("y")) {
   variableTest vt = new variableTest();
   vt.gatheringInfo();
  } else {
   System.out.println("You do not wish to add a value?");

  }
  variableTest vt = new variableTest();
  vt.printVariable();
 }
}
```

Comment: Where is 'myVar' defined, and how?  Please provide us with the complete source, or at least include the class structure that contains these methods, and also shows us how and where 'myVar' is defined.

Comment: Welcome to object instances, every time you use the `new` keyword, you create a new/separate/distinct object, with its own copy of all the (non-static) class fields. You made one object and gave it a value, and another object that you read from. Outside that, I would actually recommend making #gatheringInfo a static method which returns a `variableTest` result (off-topic: class names in Java should be capitalized)

Answer (score 0):

After posting my comment, I looked again at your code, and think I see your problem.

You're creating and operating on one instance of your variableTest class, but then you're creating a new instance of variableTest and are calling printVariable on that.  I'm pretty sure you want to be calling "new variableTest()" just once, outside of your 'if' block (above it) so that the same 'vt' object is used throughout your code.

ie:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Would You like to add a value?");
    String response = scnr.next();
    variableTest vt = new variableTest();
    if (response.toLowerCase().equals("y")) {
        vt.gatheringInfo();
    } else {
        System.out.println("You do not wish to add a value?");

    }
    vt.printVariable();
}
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused to what needs to be done.  If I put "new VariableTest outside of the if block, it says that the instance is ignored.  Can a getter and setter be used for transferring the variable?

Comment: what is it that says that the instance is ignored?  That makes no sense to me (yet). - There is nothing in my edit that would change anything except that the last line of main() will operate on the same object that gatheringInfo() was called on. - that's what you want, right?

Comment: I just noticed that you updated your answer to include the class and the definition of 'myVar'.  From all I see, if you make the change I suggest, all will be well.  Maybe you can better explain the problem you see when attempting my solution.  Have you run it?  I'm just trying to help you, btw...I don't need to be right.  I'm wrong every day.

Comment: What I want is to allow the user to type in the variable's value with the Scanner class  and that value is carried on to the printVariable method.  I think I would need a parameter somewhere right?

Comment: no.  all of your methods are in the same object, and that object contains the value 'myVar', so all of those methods have implicit access to that value.  This is a key idea of object oriented programming.  The class encapsulates the data, and the methods operate on that data.

Comment: Another way to say it is that 'this' is your variable.  That explicitly says "access the object I'm currently in".  Within this is stored myVar.  That's why you can say "this.myVar".  But you can also say "myVar", and Java will imply "this.myVar" unless you have a clashing definition of "myVar".

Comment: Please take the line "float myVar;" out of your program.  It isn't doing anything useful, and could cause confusion.

Comment: You're obviously very new to this.  I would spend the time working through some basic Java tutorials that will really teach you how object oriented programming works in Java and in general.

Comment: coolio!  Best of luck. (feel free to accept my answer if it was in fact what you were looking for, not for me, but for those who might follow)